# facebook code not working on local machine

Tags: facebook, post, message, local

I am using the below code and trying to run on my local machine. I am not able to connect with the facebook. what might be the problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '', // App ID
            channelUrl : ' ', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
    function publish(){
          FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
              message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
        };
}
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
      </script>
    <button onclick="publish()">PUBLISH ON FACEBOOK</button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: And you're including the FB libraries... where? FB has delusions of grandeur and of illusions of being indispensible,b ut it's not yet so big that its libraries are built into browsers by default.

Comment: What are FB libraries? where should i include it? If u are asking about APP ID, i have it and channel URL i have left it blank since it is optional. Sorry i am new to this thing so i am asking this trivial doubt..

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine (given that you are passing a correct app ID) - but you should test from an online environment. One way to do this, while still testing from your local machine is by editing your hosts file so that when you go to `http://example.com` it links to your `http://localhost/yourapp`

Here's how to do it:

Windows:  -

- http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp (your localhost URL should have a valid website format: 127.0.0.1 dummydomainname.tld)
- MacOS: http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-setup-virtual-hosts-mamp-environment/ (again, make sure you have a valid website format)

Once you did this, go back to your app settings and edit the "App domains" field to point to your virtual host.

To be honest, you're better off trying this on an actual server. You can consider phpfog.com or heroku.com (you get a link to create an Heroku account straight from the app settings dashboard).

Comment: Modifying your hosts file _does not_ make your local test server an “online environment” – it just changes the way your browser does DNS resolution for the hostname you are using while calling your test scripts. This is not necessary though, because testing via `http://localhost/…` works perfectly fine (unless you are using stuff that needs Facebook’s servers getting data from/connecting to your domain, f.e. sharing a link - but setting up a domain in your own hosts file does not have any benefits in that regard either).

Answer (score 0):

To develop locally, first change the settings in the facebook app settings:

> Facebook-->Settings-->Basic, write *"localhost"* in the *"App
>   Domains"* field, then click on *"+Add Platform"* choose *"Web Site"*.
>
> Then in the *"Site Url"* field **write your localhost url** (e.g.:
>   `http://localhost:1337/something`).